# Why are HTTP methods recommended?

Tags: http, server, request

When making an HTTP request, why is it recommended to add an HTTP method in the header? When making a cloud function, why is it recommended to check the header to ensure that it contains the proper method?

In theory, you could just have all request methods be `GET` and the server could just do CRUD operations and send back JSON when needed. It seems like adding/checking a method in the header is just unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Are you sure that is what you mean? The standard way of expressing http method is **not** in the headers. Do you mean the standard expression, or some additional protocol which really does expect the request method to be repeated in the headers?

Comment: It is not "recommended", it's *required*.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're making an HTTP request. That means that you're following the HTTP specification, and it says that particular methods have particular meanings. If you want to use your own protocol that's not HTTP, go ahead. But then any question that begins "When making an HTTP request ..." will not be relevant.